# Sqlite - attempt to write a readonly database (Доступ только к чтению)

Tags: php, sqlite3

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с ошибкой `8 - attempt to write a readonly database [Sqlite]`. В интернете особо информации о ней нет (многие советуют поставить права 777 файлу sqlite, но это только ухудшает ситуацию).

Собственно обстановка:

Имеются два файла `test.php` и `test_web.php`, они подключены к `data.sqlite`. К `test_web.php` обращаюсь get-запросами, использую `INSERT`, чтобы записать в таблицу, и вывожу ошибку через `$db->lastErrorMsg()` - получаю `attempt to write a readonly database`.

Далее решил проверить, как это все пройдет в ssh, переделал файл под $argv, написал в ssh и все отлично работает. Внимательно посмотрел файлы, заметил, что они все пренадлежат root (apache2 работает через www-root), решил через `chown -R www-root:www-root` сделать владельца и группу www-root (для базы Sqlite + test_web.php) и в результате получилось:

`14 - unable to open database file`

То есть доступ вообще исчез .
Мучаюсь уже два дня, пожалуйста, подскажите как решить проблему.

Answer (score 2):

**Убедитесь**, что каталог, содержащий файл базы данных, также доступен для записи пользователю, выполняющему сценарий CGI:

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/database/ 
chown www-data:www-data /var/database/DATABASE.sqlite
```

[Официальный FAQ:](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWikiFaq)

> Q) I get the following error:
>
> ```
> attempt to write a readonly database
> ```
>
> But when I try the obvious fix (making it not read-only), I get the
>   following error:
>
> ```
> unable to open database file
> ```
>
> What's up with that? I'm accessing through the pysqlite wrapper in a
>   cgi-script.
>
> A) Make sure that the directory containing the database file is also
>   writable to the user executing the CGI script.

Comment: Проделал действия, в моём случае была дериктория ` /var/www/www-root/data/www/domain/controller/data.sqlite` дал группу всем дерикториям кроме var и www-root, теперь ошибка `8 - attempt to write a readonly database`

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с такой же ошибкой, изменения прав не помогали, выключил систему во время работы скрипта который обращался к БД,база зависла в режиме readonly, помогло удаление временных файлов - `*dbname*-journal`